# Areas do not work in ASP.NET 6 with Angular project

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have created an dotnet angular project with the command:

```
dotnet new angular -o my-new-app
```

My app is working fine. But now I want to add areas in the controller. My sample code is given bellow:

**Program.cs file:**

```
app.MapControllerRoute("areas", "{areas:exist}/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

**proxy.conf.js file**

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
       "/Sys/airport",
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]
```

**Controller file**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[area]/[controller]")]
[Area("Sys")]
```

**Folder Structure**

```
Areas\Sys\Controllers
AirportController.cs
```

**Api URL**

```
'/sys/airport/GetGridData'
```

Now data is coming without using area. But when I use area it shows 404 error.

Can any any one help me?

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Comment: Still not. I am trying to fix it.

Comment: Please show us the pic about your error, or debug details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `GetGridData` is a View, you should add below code in `Program.cs` file.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// add below code
builder.Services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
    options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml");
    options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml");
});

...

app.MapControllerRoute("areas", "{areas:exist}/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");;

app.Run();
```

If your `GetGridData` is a api interface, it's ok, you don't need add code above.  Whatever GetGridData is, we need to add [HttpGet("GetGridData")] to the method. This should fix the issue.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace my_new_app.Areas.Sys.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[area]/[controller]")]
    [Area("Sys")]
    public class AirportController : Controller
    {
        // add this attribute
        [HttpGet("GetGridData")]
        public IActionResult GetGridData()
        {
            return View();
        }
        // add this attribute
        [HttpGet("GetGridData1")]
        public string GetGridData1()
        {
            return "111";
        }
    }
}
```